# Reassigning local commits to a different branch in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I'm using hg bookmarks in my repo because they allow me to work with ease on different features. The thing with Mercurial is that, still, all commits are associated with a branch. So, what I did is that I have a lot of local changes, with a lot of pulled (but not updated changes) to the same branch. In other words, my local repo looks like this:

```
default     -------E-F---------
newf        -A-C-D---------J---
newf,bmark  --\--------H-I----K
```

`newf` is a branch that is on remote, pulled up to J, and `bmark` is the bookmark I created. Everything in `newf`, marked with `bmark` is strictly local to my machine.

Now, I would like to re-assign H, I, and K (actually, there are ~20 changes) to a different branch, which I can push to the repo. Is there a way to do it in Mercurial, so that my working copy (I still have some uncommitted changes) remains as unaffected as possible?

Based on the suggestion to use 'rebase', I tried the following steps:

```
hg up -r A
hg branch newbranch && hg ci -m "will hold some development"
# This effectively made a commit X
hg up bmark
hg rebase -d newbranch
```

Apart from getting some errors about phases, the rebase gives me something I would not expect:

```
default     -------E-F---------
newf        -A-C-D---------J---
newf,bmark    \   -----H-I----K
newbranch      \X/
```

That is, `H`,`I`, and `K` are listed to still belong to `newf` and `bmark`, and they are on top on commit `X` that belongs to branch `newbranch`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I use [rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) to move commits from one branch to another. Would it work in your case?

Comment: I added the results of using rebase in my case. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but rebase does not help.

Comment: @NikolaKnezevic I think you need to specify a `--source` branch and from the looks of it you want `--detach` as well. What documentation did you read?

Comment: I tried also using `--source` (as in `hg up -r X && hg rebase -s K`) but this didn't work for some reason. I read the wiki you linked and `hg -v help rebase` (btw, it mentions that -D is deprecated).

Comment: @NikolaKnezevic Im prepared to take another stab at this. Maybe its time for you to create a mini-repos and upload it to bitbucket or something. Then I could try the commands myself.

Comment: I also use `hg rebase` (with source and dest) to wrangle this kind of thing. `hg view` is helpful to figure out what revisions to use.

Comment: You may also try to graft your changesets onto your new branch and use `hg strip` to remove them from the old branch. Remember that things can go wrong when messing with mercurial history, so always have another clone of your local change.