# How to push, without creating new heads, after creating multi-head branch, rebase and several merges

Tags: mercurial

I did a series of dumb steps with *my local copy* of our shared repository, and I'm looking for a way how to fix it. The steps are:

- I used bookmarks to have multiple heads of a development branch, that other people use:

  ```
  -o---o---o-----o---   <- dev branch
    \----1----1------   <- another head of the dev branch,
                           where I committed stuff
  ```
- I created a new branch, still local, some time later

  ```
    /---------------x   <- new branch
  -o---o---o-----o---   <- dev branch
    \----1----1------   <- another head of the dev branch,
                           where I committed stuff
  ```
- for one head, that contains only my code, I did a rebase on another branch

  ```
                     /-1'--1'--  <- rebase
    /---------------x            <- new branch
  -o---o---o-----o---            <- dev branch
    \----1----1------            <- another head of the dev branch,
                                    where I committed stuff
  ```
- then, I merged the rebase, and then, a couple of commits later, I merged default

  ```
                     ----------d-\      <-default
                                  \
                     /-1'--1'\     \
    /---------------x--------x--x-x-x-- <- new branch 
  -o---o---o-----o---         
    \----1----1------
  ```

Now, I wanted to push my new branch to the server (`hg push --new-branch -b newBranch`), but I get `abort: push creates new remote head`, since commits `1'` belong to dev branch.

What is the right thing to do? I would like to avoid creating this additional head.

*Update*:

Per request, this is the output of `hg heads`:

```
changeset:   839:f2033d695fcd  <- want to push this
branch:      newBranch
tag:         tip
user:        me
date:        Wed Oct 31 13:05:51 2012 +0100

changeset:   826:7fde19d7f467
branch:      devBranch
user:        my-collegue
date:        Tue Oct 23 14:59:42 2012 +0200

changeset:   820:23853bbf68df  <- the part after rebase that got merged
branch:      devBranch
user:        me
date:        Mon Oct 22 15:36:26 2012 +0200

changeset:   807:899344cfb145  <- obsolete (branch with 1's)
branch:      devBranch
parent:      711:454f29c03fb1
user:        me
date:        Mon Oct 22 15:36:26 2012 +0200

changeset:   712:d5e8a62a7f5f  <- default, needs to stay
parent:      648:2bbcc01aa191
user:        me
date:        Wed Aug 22 16:21:09 2012 +0200
```

Comment: Don't use free-hand "drawing" - you have console commands and ability to paste commands output in question **formatted** (`hg log` or `hg glog` for tree here and at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982648/reassigning-local-commits-to-a-different-branch-in-mercurial, for example). For now, please, add output of `hg heads` with comment - which head is obsolete and must not exist (totally or only in push-target). Also read about -r option in push command

Comment: Hi @LazyBadger, I can't provide you the output of `log` as there are much more commits than I described, and I also forgot the exact commands I executed in order to get to this state... Question updated to contain the output of heads. I don't understand your reference to `-r` option, how/why should it help?

Comment: exact commands doesn't needed in this case - **you** (not I) have to see tree of devBranch ( from common parent of 807 and 820 to 826), define the *possibility* (and *necessity*) of merging devBranch's heads. Or just `push -r f2033d695fcd` will be enough

Comment: @LazyBadger, if I try `hg push -r f2033d695fcd --new-branch`, I get `abort: push creates new remote head 23853bbf68df on branch devBranch`. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Merge at least *this head* (all will be better)

Comment: Did you try `hg commit --close-branch` on the obsolete branch?  If you didn't push the obsolete branch, you could also `hg strip` the obsolete branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, without pushing another head to the repo, and without merging `23853bbf68df` onto `newBranch`. This is probably not the cleanest way to do it, but I will leave it as a reference. In a nutshell, I reconstructed the whole branch by taking all commits and re-applying them.

First, I killed the `newBranch`'es head `899344cfb145`, by using strip on the first diverging revision I did:

```
hg strip -r 646
```

Then, I produced email patches (couldn't play with mq) for all commits that are in `newBranch`, since it's inception:

```
hg export -g -r 797:808 -r 810 -r 815:822 -r 824:830 -o "%n-%m.patch"
```

- `797:808` are the patches in `newBranch` that were in the rebased part of `devBranch` (`1'` commits from the original figure).
- `810` and `815:822` are other patchs in `newBranch`. `811:814` belong to a different branch, so I had to exclude those.
- `823` is a merge commit with `default`, so I skipped this one.
- `824:830` are all the commits after the merge with `default`.

Now, I imported these patches on a new head of `newBranch`:

```
hg up -r 796
# there are 29 patches, applying till merge
hg import --bypass {01..21}*.patch
hg up tip
hg merge default
hg ci -m 'merging in default'
hg import --bypass {22..28}*.patch
```

Finally, I just stripped of the original head of `newBranch`.

```
hg strip -r 797
```

This may not work in every situation. During the merge, I had to resolve some conflicts, too, but pretty benign. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

You can push only the one head you're interested in mercurial.  For you that would mean doing:

```
hg push -r f2033d695fcd
```

If the destination repo has been updated you need to pull, merge, and re-push:

```
hg pull
hg up -r <remote head>
hg merge -r f2033d695fcd
hg ci
hg push
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I mentioned, this produces `abort: push creates new remote head 23853bbf68df on branch devBranch`. As @LazyBadger suggests, I will try merging this head, although that is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: That's a different head than the one you are actually trying to push.  If you specify the head you are trying to push with `-r` you will not get this head.